# I am looking to plot a histogram from the lorenz model

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, histogram, attributeerror

I am looking to plot a histogram from matplotlib, specifically the x1 variable. However, I am having trouble navigating the histogram. At the moment, I have:

```
43: h = plt.hist(y[:, 0])
44: h.plot(y[:, 0])
45: h.set_xlabel('$x_1$')
46: plt.show()
```

I am getting the error:  File "/Users/scottdayton/PycharmProjects/Uncertainty Research/lorenz.py", line 44, in 
    h.plot(y[:, 0])
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'plot'

How can I get the histogram to plot the values I am getting? (y[:, 0])

Answer (score 0):

You're operating on the tuple returned by `plt.hist()`. This tuple contains values of histogram bins, bin edges, patches. These are usually not needed for the plot itself.

You should only operate on the `plt` interface, or preferably OO interface (`axes`) which you seem to be not using here.

As far as I can understand from the incomplete code, line 44 is not needed.  Fix the line 45 with:

```
plt.set_xlabel('$x_1$')
```

Also just make sure to enable the LaTeX support by importing:

```
from matplotlib import rc
rc('text', usetex=True)
```

Hopefully, that should fix the issue. For a complete histogram plot please see: [PyPlot Text histogram](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/pyplots/pyplot_text.html#sphx-glr-gallery-pyplots-pyplot-text-py)